# Можно сказать: уходил охотой?

Tags: лексика, падежи

Есть такой текст:

*К тому же королевский двор почти беспрестанно находился в движении. Инспектировал местность, кочуя из одной крепости в другую... А то **уходил охотой** на многие дни и многие, многие километры.*

Нужно исправить: ***на охоту***?

Comment: Я думаю, что здесь **охота** в значении 4, а не 1 [по Кузнецову](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0&all=x). Но всё равно не уверен в правильности употребления (просто никогда не встречал в литературе в таком сочетании).

Comment: Спасибо, интересно. А почему комментарий, а не ответ. Хотела вам плюсик поставить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто *редкий случай*, когда "охота" (собаки да егеря) *сама* куда-то отправляется - *двор*  в специфическом составе, но без своего хозяина. В литературе находится лишь предложный вариант, когда "*император Пётр **со** своею многочисленной **охотой** подъезжал*" (Е. Карнович, Придворное кружево). А так выражение "двор уходил охотой" мало чем отличается от похода куда-нибудь "ротой", "бригадой" или "пожарным расчётом". Поэтому выглядит допустимым.

Comment: Спасибо, мне тоже этот вариант кажется допустимым. Другое дело, если не очень продвинутый в теме читатель не поймет, о какой охоте идет речь.